# UWP CustomControl as a drop container at design time

Tags: uwp, mode

Because in a UWP application there is no form of layout inheritance one is forced to use a CustomControl as the base for the layout.

How in a UWP app can the CustomControl be used as drop target in design mode? So that, say a button dropped from the design palette becomes contained within the CustomControl.

All the documentation I can find relates to a WPF app and doesn't apply to a UWP app.

Any complete examples much appreciated.

Comment: You should use a `UserControl` and then you can drop elements onto it in Blend (Design time)

Comment: My current version is derived from a UserControl but I still can't drop items into it all that happens is that the items end up on top of may layout.

Comment: can you post all the xaml please?

Answer (score 0):

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Name="userControl"
    x:Class="Ids2.ProgramBaseLayout"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Ids2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400" Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource programBaseLayoutStyle}}"
>

    <Grid Background="{Binding ContentAreaBackground, ElementName=userControl}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="9*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Title, ElementName=userControl}" VerticalAlignment="Top" MinWidth="30"/>
        <Frame x:Name="frame" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
     </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The Code:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;

// The User Control item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234236

namespace Ids2
{
    public sealed partial class ProgramBaseLayout : UserControl
    {
        public ProgramBaseLayout()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string Title
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
             DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(ProgramBaseLayout), null);

        public Brush ContentAreaBackground
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(ContentAreaBackgroundProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ContentAreaBackgroundProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentAreaBackgroundProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ContentAreaBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(ProgramBaseLayout), null);
    }
}
```

When a button is drop it doesn't end up inside the Frame it ends up on top of the control.
It would be nice if the drop could be limited only to dropping inside the Frame.